# Is there any way to have readonly feature without using get() in get() set() model?

Tags: java, oop, private

Having the get set model:

```
public class exampleclass
{
    private Something something;

    public Something getSomething()
    {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(Something st)
    {
         something = st;
    }
}
```

I wanna make something like this:

```
public class exampleclass
{
    public Something something;

    public void setSomething(Something st)
    {
         something = st;
    }
}
```

But i want to have "something" var with ***readOnly* feature out of the class** (but rewritable in the own class). Any idea of how to do this for an optimized access. (Think this is gonna be used in android , but using a pure java only framework (libgdx) )

Comment: What do you mean saying *optimized*? Such calls will be JITted, even on dalvik (well, on recent versions of dalvik).

Comment: do you mean get() calls are already optimized?

Comment: Yes, [since Gingerbread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4930538/298389). And it's definitely can be optimized by Hotspot.

Comment: but one of the thing android says is : Avoid using get set functions to not overload calling more encapsulated functions.

Comment: No get() calls are not always optimized! For that reason java.awt.Point have direct access to x, and y (point.x, point.y) because in graphics high performance is needed.

Comment: @AlexWien are we talking about [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) optimization? ;-) JIT doesn't optimize **any** calls, but frequent ones. BTW, can you provide a reference to the statement, that direct access to java.awt.Point was designed in such way, to eliminate function call overhead?

Comment: JIT compiles. sometimes it can inline getter, but not always.

Comment: @AlexWien I've [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902682/is-there-any-way-to-have-readonly-feature-without-using-get-in-get-set-mod/13902714#comment19157814_13902682) a link on the words of Google engineer (from Android JIT team) which says that *this particular getter* (e.g. just field read, no conditionals) will be JITted. Sorry, if I confused you and made thinking that I'm stating that any call can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i will read it later. JITed does not mean inlined (Or does it?) . JIT could compile the get method, having one indirection, still in assembler

Comment: @AlexWien, yes, it does mean inlining (the link is in 3rd comment, btw).

Comment: I dont think so, that depens on the getter, if it is a huge getter with 2000 lines of code it will not be inlined. See c compiler. all is compiled, but not all is inlined. A standard getter may be inlined

Comment: @AlexWien the public access to the coordinates of `java.awt.Point` is generally [considered a mistake](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=effective+java+awt+point&source=bl&ots=D3ya-8tEAl&sig=0Pxn00mya2BwC1UbJLbkriXheuc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GwLOUPS9Lef_igLvsIEI&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20awt%20point&f=false) by the authors of Java that can't be corrected now.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Josh Bloch is one of the java authors, he did not implement class Point. i remember that the  author of Point or somebody else at Sun, stated that they had a perfomance problem when x and y would not be directly accessible. further it is horrible using getters in geometric formulas.

Answer (score 3):

You can set thoose things in constructor and expose public final field:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public final Something something;

    public ExampleClass(Something st)
    {
         something = st;
    }
}
```

Comment: but what i want is to reuse that var , not creating more objects .

Comment: Sorry i think i've explained it bad , what i want is readonly for outter class calls.

Comment: @A.Quiroga then, I'm not aware of any elegant way to perform such things without some kind of getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the final keyword.
The you can assign it once.

e.g

```
public class Exampleclass
{
    public final Something something;
    void Exampleclass(Something init) {
        this.something = init;
    }
}
```

However the content of Something still could be changed, so you may consider returning a clone() of something. (see the class java.util.Date, you still could set the timestamp, in such cases only clone() or a copy constructor helps) . But if your code is not a public lib, then you can leav that getter with clone() away

```
public class Exampleclass
    {
        private Something something;
        void Exampleclass(Something init) {
            this.something = init;
        }
       void Something getSomething() {
            return something.clone();
        }

    }
```

But that depends on Something.
Another soultion is a `Factory Pattern`, such that only the `Factory` can create `Something`.
Then there is no `public constructor` in `Something`. Only the factory can create it.

```
public class Something() {
   private int value;
   protectectd Something(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
   public tostring() {
      System.out.println("values = " + value);
   }
}
public class SomethingFactory() {
  protected static Someting createSomething(int value)  {
     return new Something(value);   
 }
}
```

USage:

```
Something some = SomethingFactory.createSomething(3);
```

But read more by search "java  Deisgn Patterns Factory" or FactoryPattern

Comment: but what i want is optimized access also . cloning isnt optimized and have nonsense since what i want is not need of get() call but directly using the var

Comment: then use the final approach and make something protected or public

Comment: but final approach can't set more than once the var

Comment: final, yes once, you wanted it read only! Otherwise you coul duse  A factory pattern, such that only the factory can construct Something. and the factro is protected in that package.

Comment: that's the question , if i put direct access to Something , the var will be writable (which is what i dont want) .

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is escaping reference, if you want to save your object while returning,  send a copy of reference, you can send cloned object using clone method.

```
public Something getSomething()
{
    return something.clone();
}
```

This will return object shallow copy, if you want make deep cloning override the clone() method Hope this will help..