# What optimizations does Dalvik JIT compilation do?

Tags: java, android, compiler-optimization, dalvik

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912695/567555) but is being asked over two years after, with Dalvik JIT compilation being there for a long time now.

I want to know the kind of optimizations Dalvik will do for me, for example, function inlining, common subexpression elimination, optimizing away array-bounds checks, etc. Can I expect Dalvik optimizations to be roughly on par with desktop JVMs like HotSpot?

Comment: I think you are missing what the JIT is doing. Have you seen this Google IO session on Dalvik JIT: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/jit-compiler-androids-dalvik-vm.html

Comment: The source code for Dalvik is available and an obvious source of this information: https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/ Also, "roughly on par" doesn't really mean anything. Dalvik might take a *vastly* different approach to things compared to HotSpot.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, yes but there must be changes over these years.

Comment: @Morrison Chang, the link provided doesn't contain the Dalvik source code. It contains the Dalvik Profiler.

Comment: @millimoose agreed on both your points. Yet it is not that easy for me to go lookup at the source code and see what has been done. Hoping to see if someone here knows those things. As for your second point, feel free to suggest a better wording -- I just want to know what kind of performance/optimizations to expect and perhaps a comparison with Desktop JVMs.

Comment: "there must be changes over these years" is a false presumption. But you might get better responses if you specified what you're actually looking for. As it is, your post isn't much of a question, and it's hardly constructive. This would be a better fit for a discussion forum.

Comment: @r.v I understand that, but it's not really the right kind of question on SO. Ideally the questions should be ones where someone with more expertise than you in the general area can work out the answer. Questions where a good answer can really only come from a fairly small group of people (the Dalvik team) who might or might not be on SO don't really count as "answerable", and would be better directed to a specific forum. (Unless you're asking about C# specifically, because that summons Eric Lippert with some reliability.)

Comment: @r.v Another problem is scope. A question where a solid answer would have to be the length of an in-depth blog post requiring research in the order of hours is definitely pushing it.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks! The question that I linked to in my question is also similar though. Do you think I should make it more specific to particular optimizations I am expecting, or something like that?

Comment: @r.v That question was highly specific, which might have helped things. That said, I'd consider at least grepping through the Dalvik source before asking, to show your own research, and give people who want to answer a starting point. (E.g. "I found function `foo()` which seems like it might imply optimization *bar* but it's not really clear" etc.) And, obviously, I can't actually guarantee it getting answered or not closed - SO trends towards more strictness over time. I'd probably have just passed the question you linked to by without voting either way for whatever that's worth.