# Is Android internal getter/setter really a code smell?

Tags: java, android, performance, lint

In Android documentation there is an [article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) about "Performance Tips" that recommends avoiding theuse of internal getters/setters.
A recent [publication](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01276904) in the [MOBILESoft 2016](http://mobilesoftconf.org/2016/) conference agrees with this recommendation.

However, according to the [lint documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks):

> As of Android 2.3 (Gingerbread), this optimization is performed
>   automatically by Dalvik, so there is no need to change your code; this is only
>   relevant if you are targeting older versions of Android.

Is there any official and updated information regarding this?

Comment: According to this answer from "Ben, one of the engineers working on the JIT @ Google" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912695/what-optimizations-can-i-expect-from-dalvik-and-the-android-toolchain/4930538#4930538 you don't need to worry about using internal getters/setters starting from Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Comment: Android has a limitation of 64k methods (in total of all classes of your app) per dex file. Therefore saving unnecessary methods may make sense if your app grows larger.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give my opinion about the publication, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912695/what-optimizations-can-i-expect-from-dalvik-and-the-android-toolchain/4930538#4930538) can support what lint documentation says.

My own guideline is prefer clean code / structure (in this case if you don't use getter/setter, you might have code duplications scattered across your classes and makes changes would be hard because you need to do it in some places) rather than micro performance improvement.